# Python urllib proxy

Tags: python, proxy, mechanize

I'm trying to fetch some urls via urllib and mechanize through my proxy.

With mechanize I try the following:

```
from mechanize import Browser
import re

br = Browser()
br.set_proxies({"http": "MYUSERNAME:*******@itmalsproxy.italy.local:8080"})
br.open("http://www.example.com/")
```

I get the following error:

```
httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy service is denied.
```

As the proxy, the username and the password are correct, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the proxy is using NTLM authentication?

If that is the case, you can try using the [NTLM Authorization Proxy Server](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/) (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130857/following-a-javascript-postback-using-com-ie-automation-to-save-text-file/1131150#1131150)).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i tried with http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/ and still get the very same error

Comment: I do not believe that python-ntlm supports NTML proxies (only direct HTTP connections). Did you try NTLM authorization proxy server?

Answer (score 0):

you might get more info from the response headers

`print br.response().info()`

Answer (score 0):

When your web browser uses proxy server to surf the Web from within your local
network your may be required to authenticate youself to use proxy.  Google ntlmaps.